# SVC Gridsearch is very slow

Tags: python, svc

The following code is very slow, even if I increase cache_size to 2000:

```
svc_param_grid = {'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear', 'poly', 'sigmoid'],
                'gamma': np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1).tolist(),
                'C': np.logspace(-15, 15, num=100, base=2.0).tolist(),
                'coef0':np.arange(0.0, 10, 0.1).tolist(), 
                'degree':np.arange(0.0, 10, 0.1).tolist(),
                'tol':np.arange(0.001,0.1,0.001).tolist(),
                'decision_function_shape':['ovo', 'ovr']}
```

Comment: There are too many combinations, it is suppose to be slow.

Comment: Thanks, Akshay.  Is there a way to improve performance by breaking it up in a smart way?